# Restrict HTTP access in CakePHP

Tags: php, class, security, web, cakephp

I have a Controller class that extends from AppController in CakePHP.
And this Controller class has a public function .. lets say `testFunc()`

```
    class xyzController extends AppController {
          ..
          ..
          public function testFunc($params, $auth_username)
          {
                 ..
                 ..
          }
    }
```

I have made this function public since I need to call it from another Controller that too extending from AppController.

```
class abcController extends AppController {
      ..
      ..
      public function callingFunc()
      {
             ...
             $controller = new xyzController($this->request, $this->response);
             $controller->testFunc($params, $username);
      }
      ..
      ..
}
```

But since I made it public, I see that `testFunc()` is accessible using curl command for the below https path

```
https://[ip_address]/xyz/testFunc/arg=test/root
```

As you can see, the above path takes "root" as argument to testFunc() and gives full access to anyone using the above path in curl command.

My requirement is to remove this security issue.

I am totally new to PHP and CakePHP. Can someone please give any pointers to how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.

public function _testFunc($params, $auth_usernmae) will do the magic.

In Cakephp, if the function has an underscore as prefix, then it cannot be accessed using URI but can be accessed internally from other functions.

Answer (score 2):

"I need to call it from another Controller". This is almost never actually true, it usually indicates a flawed design. If `testFunc` is not meant to be accessed through a browser, then move it to somewhere that both controllers can access it without it being a public member. For example, make it a protected (or even private) member of your `AppController`, or if it's doing model-specific stuff, maybe it can be moved to that model's table class.

Comment: This is the existing design. I won't be able to change it. Is there any way to make testFunc private, so that it can't be accessed using normal HTTP request?

Comment: @AthulSukumaran You said that _you_ changed this to a public method, so apparently you _can_ change the design to some degree? There's really no point in working around such fundamental architectural problems, they should be fixed! Don't let anyone else whose maybe working on the project tell you otherwise.

Comment: "I won't be able to change it." I would say the opposite: You can and must change it immediately, as pointed out this is a flaw in the design and compromises the way this is supposed to work. Put it into a component or alike instead.